# Batch code does not work with case-insensitive input for a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created the below code to execute multiple commands depending on the user input but the input is case-sensitive.

I have tried the `/I` switch with the `if` statement but that does not work either.

Below is the code:

```
@Echo off
SET /P uname=Launch Outlook in safe mode: 
IF "%uname%"==Yes GOTO Error
IF "%uname%"==No GOTO start
:Error
taskkill /IM Outlook.exe /f
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
start Outlook.exe /safe
@echo The Script is running please wait && timeout /t 20
taskkill /IM Outlook.exe /f
cd %Homepath%
cd Appdata\Local\Temp
echo.>myfile.txt && @echo Thanks for using the script,You may close this window.and continue. > myfile.txt
start outlook.exe
timeout /t 8
start notepad myfile.txt
:End
:start
echo "No valid options"
echo "This window would close in 10 seconds" && timeout /t 10
:End
```

Comment: put *both*  sides of the comparison into quotes: `if /i "%uname%" == "Yes" ...`

Comment: Also when are looking for pre-determined​ responses, use `choice.exe`, if available. _It's so much easier than creating a bunch of scenarios for unexpected user input_. Type `CHOICE /?` for more information.

Comment: Besides the fact that your `if` clauses cannot match as pointed out by Stephan, what do you think happens when the user enters neither `Yes` nor `No`? where do you think execution is will continue then?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the choice command instead

```
echo Y] Yes
echo N] No
choice /c yn /n
if %errorlevel%==1 goto yes
if %errorlevel%==2 goto yes
```